# Unknown error on CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm a begginer in programing and I'm starting to get used to C/C++. While trying to do a code that i found on a exercise, I'm getting this error. If someone could help, I would appreciate a lot.

```
float matrx [50][50];
float *p;
p = matrx;
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<50; i++)
    for (j=0; j<50; j++)
        p[i][j]=0.0;
printf("%f",p[2][2]);
return(0);
```

The error displayed is:
"error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector."

Comment: Is there a reason for the extra pointer variable `p`? Why not just print `matrx` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

p is a pointer to float. For your code to work, p has to be pointer to array of float:

```
   float (*p)[50];
   p = matrx;
```

Note that `float **p;` would be wrong, since an array is not the same thing as a pointer in C, and a two-dimensional array is not the same thing as a pointer to pointer.

I assume the point of the exercise is to show this. Otherwise, you could just skip `p`, and use `matrx` directly.

Answer (score 1):

`float matrx [50][50]` and `float *p` are very different things.  Changing your code slightly works fine:

```
float p[50][50];
int i,j;
for (i=0; i<50; i++)
    for (j=0; j<50; j++)
        p[i][j]=0.0;
printf("%f",p[2][2]);
return(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pointer like this

```
T *p;
```

where `T` is some type then `p[i]` where `i` is some index is an object of type `T`.

Thus relative to your code if you defined pointer like

```
float *p;
```

then `p[i]` is already an object of type `float` and you may not apply to it the subscript operator like `p[i][j]`.

In C++ and C multidimensional arrays are in fact one-dimensional arrays elements of which are in turn arrays.

So if you have declaration

```
float matrx [50][50];
```

then using a typedef you could write

```
typedef float T[50];

T matric[50];
```

And the corresponding pointer would look like

```
T *p = matrix;
```

where `T` as it follows from the typedef is `float[50]`

So p is a pointer to an object of this type

```
float ( *p )[50];
```

In this case you may write

```
p = matrix;
```

Comment: Thanks, great explanation. I had already got an answer, but anyway, you've helped a lot.